# Testing an app on the device

Tags: iphone, testing

For some reason i cant test my apps on a real iphone anymore. My license is valid the device has a profile, but something just doesn't seem to work... I think i'm doing something wrong but i don't know what exactly... the App Id, the Profile??

Can you please list me all the steps of testing an app? before i could do it myself but now i just don't get it anymore...

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: When you connect your device, go into Xcode's organizer and see if there is anything there.  At one point I thought I had deployed a profile but when I went into organizer it wasn't there.

Comment: Do you have any build warnings / errors? What do they say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head here are some things to check:

1. Go into the organisier check the provisioning profile, check it hasn't expired and that the app identifier is generic (or matches your app)
2. Check the keychain.  It should have your developer certificate attached with your private key
3. Open up the target in XCode, check the code signing identity. (make sure it has a specific name not just "iPhone Developer")